# Updating the files with new file

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, c#-4.0

1. I have 1,000 Uniquely named folders in one large folder.
2. Inside of each uniquely named folder these is another folder called /images.
3. Inside each image folder there is a file named `"Read-Web-Site-Design-{UNIQUEFOLDERNAME}-ca-logo.png"`
4. I want to  replace the 1,768 `.png` files (while keeping the original name) from a `.png` file which I am supplying.

The folder structure and filenames need to remain same.  Basically I'm  updating the old file with a new file, using the same (unique) name, 1,000 times.

I have written this code and I am able to get all the files and directories in loop but I want to know how will I update files here,please check my code:

```
private List<String> DirSearch(string sDir)
{
List<String> files = new List<String>();
try
{
    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(sDir))
    {
        files.Add(f);

    }
    foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
    {
        files.AddRange(DirSearch(d));
    }
}
catch (System.Exception excpt)
{
    //MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
}

return files;
}
```

Comment: Which langauge you want to use? I'm weird of your tags.

Comment: @Lucas Thanks....c# or vb.net anyone..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply you have to do a `File.Copy()` to replace old files with new .png file you are supplying.

Assuming you will have all the files to be replaced in the list,

```
  List<String> files = new List<String>();

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(file))
        {
            File.Copy("New File Path", "file to be replaced", true);
        }
    }
```

See, you are passing `true` as the 3rd parameter of the Copy() method, Which is to overrite if there is a file already in the destination path.

or you can use `File.Replace()`. Here you can keep the original file as a backup.

```
File.Replace("New File", "File to be replaced", "Back up of Original File");
```

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to consider the following, It will handle the recursion for you, only find png files that have "Read-Web-Site" in their file path

```
foreach(var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, "*.png", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                           .Where(x => x.Contains("Read-Web-Site")))
{
 File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(new FileInfo(file).DirectoryName,"newName.png"), true);
}
```

If its another file you wish to overwrite to this file instead then its the same but

```
File.Copy("newFile", file, true);
```

**Edit**

Even better

```
foreach(var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, 
    "Read-Web-Site*.png",
     SearchOption.AllDirectories))
```